# Text ist nicht verständlich genug

Tags: word-choice

Ich habe meine Abschlussarbeit von einem Experten korrigieren lassen.

Original war der Text:

> Die folgende Formel gibt das nächstgelegene Alter eines Benutzers aus,
>   völlig unabhängig davon, ob er jünger oder älter ist:

Geändert wurde der Text in:

> Die folgende Formel gibt das diesem Wunschalter am nächsten kommende
>   Alter eines Benutzers aus, völlig unabhängig davon, ob er jünger oder
>   älter ist:

Ich finde, dass der korrigierter Text etwas schwierig zu verstehen ist. Hätte jemand einen Alternativvorschlag für mich?

Comment: Ohne etwas mehr Kontext ist es praktisch unmöglich, hier eine bessere Formulierung zu finden. Die Version des Korrektors klingt zwar etwas umständlich, aber ich ahne, was gemeint ist - es ist aber dennoch ein wenig raten dabei. Außerdem besteht die Gefahr, wenn hier jemand, der zwar seine Muttersprache Deutsch sehr gut beherrscht, aber mit der Fachterminologie Deines Gebietes nicht vertraut ist, einen zwar wohlklingenden, aber eben auch laienhaft formulierten Vorschlag anbringt.

Comment: Ist das nächstgelegene Alter nicht einfach immer das tatsächliche Alter? Also für jmd., der 23 ist, was soll da das nächstgelegene Alter sein? 25, weil es näher liegt als 20, für einen 22jährigen aber 20, nicht 25, weil auf 5 Jahre gerundet wird? Was hat das mit Wunschalter zu tun? Geht es um Partnersuche?

Comment: Willst du "word-choice" oder eine andere Satzstruktur? Letztere finde ich auch nicht gut.

Comment: @Cacambo am liebsten schon eine andere Satzstruktur.

Comment: @userunknown man kann es schon mit Partnersuche vergleichen. Wenn das Wunschalter als 25 ist, soll der Benutzer also eher 29 sein als 20.

Comment: Gut, dann wäre noch zu fragen, was die Betonung "völlig unabhängig" gegenüber "unabhängig" betonen soll - was könnte man sich denn unter "ein wenig unabhängig" in diesem Kontext vorstellen?

Comment: @userunknown sehr gute Frage! Das kann man ruhig weglassen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Das Alter eines Benutzers, das diesem Wunschalter am nächsten kommt, gibt die folgende Formel aus – gleich, ob jünger oder älter.

oder

> Das Alter eines Benutzers, das diesem Wunschalter am nächsten kommt – gleich, ob jünger oder älter –, gibt die folgende Formel aus.